# What is the name of the sequel to Manic Miner for the ZX Spectrum?

Tags: manic-miner

When I was a mere youth I had a ZX Spectrum. One of my favorite games was "Manic Miner",
but I am stumped as to the name of the sequel to this game.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sequel you are talking about is [Jet Set Willy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_Set_Willy).

Source:[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manic_Miner)

Answer (score 1):

There were two official JSW games and one that was canned when the developer, Matthew Smith, went a bit mental and ran off to Holland.

The good news is that you can play the majority of Speccy games in a browser, here:

http://www.worldofspectrum.org/games/index.html

Here's the link to JSW:

http://www.worldofspectrum.org/infoseekplay.cgi?title=Jet+Set+Willy&pub=R.D.+Foord+Software&year=1985&id=0014784&game=/games/j/JetSetWilly.tap.zip&emu=3